# Having problems installing bzr on CentOS-6.5

Tags: centos, bazaar

I am having trouble installing bzr on my CentOS-6.5 using the command:

```
#yum -y install bzr
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error: Package: bzr-2.3.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
       Requires: python-elementtree
Error: Package: python-curl-7.15.5-1.3.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
       Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: bzr-2.3.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
       Installed: python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5)
           python(abi) = 2.6
       Available: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (updates)
           python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: python-curl-7.15.5-1.3.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
       Installed: python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5)
           python(abi) = 2.6
       Available: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (updates)
           python(abi) = 2.6
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Any suggestions please?

I changed the repo to EL6 as shown below but still getting the same error:

```
# Name: RPMforge RPM Repository for Red Hat Enterprise 6 - dag
# URL: http://rpmforge.net/
[rpmforge]
name = Red Hat Enterprise $releasever - RPMforge.net - dag
#baseurl = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/$basearch/dag
mirrorlist = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/mirrors-rpmforge
#mirrorlist = file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mirrors-rpmforge
enabled = 1
protect = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmforge-dag
gpgcheck = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have EL5 rpmforge repositories set up but are using EL6 CentOS repositories.

That won't work.

You need to use the same version for both.

Comment: I changed the rpmforge to EL6, but still get the same error.

Comment: Did you clear and rebuild your yum caches? Try `yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=rpmforge clean metadata`.

Comment: Hi Etan. I was trying to install Sysbench, that is why i needed bzr. I am following instructions from http://tech-for-me.blogspot.tw/2012/07/installing-sysbench-from-launchpad.html. When i try step 5 (make), for some reason it is throwing this error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [sysbench] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/sysbench/sysbench'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
Any suggestions please?

Comment: @TheGeorgia That's a new question, feel free to ask it as one. But the answer is likely that you are missing the openssl-devel (or similar) package.

Comment: Wow Etan. You are the man! It works after installing the oppenssl-devel. Sysbench is up and running now. Thanks a million man.